# C# Why cant we directly use (double) for casting object(which is of type int) to double? What's the issue here?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        double sum = 0;

        ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
        myArrayList.Add(12);
        myArrayList.Add(13);
        myArrayList.Add(13.2);

        foreach(object i in myArrayList)
        {
            if(i is int)
            {
                sum += (double)i;
            }
            else if(i is double)
            {
                sum += (double)i;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

I get an error from running this code snippet:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Double'.'

But, the code snippet I'm about to show you doesn't throw an error and it works fine..

I just changed the `(double)` to `(int)` and it somehow worked.. But how?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        double sum = 0;

        ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
        myArrayList.Add(12);
        myArrayList.Add(13);
        myArrayList.Add(13.2);

        foreach(object i in myArrayList)
        {
            if(i is int)
            {
                sum += (int)i;
            }
            else if(i is double)
            {
                sum += (double)i;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

And this code snippet works fine as well..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        double sum = 0;

        ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
        myArrayList.Add(12);
        myArrayList.Add(13);
        myArrayList.Add(13.2);

        foreach(object i in myArrayList)
        {
            if(i is int)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToDouble(i);
            }
            else if(i is double)
            {
                sum += (double)i;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

Please explain the concept behind this to me

Comment: The `(double)` cast operator has two meanings. When applied to an arithmetic type, it means "convert this arithmetic type to double." When applied to a reference type, it means "unbox this object to a double." Since `i` is a reference type (`object`), the compiler interprets it as an unboxing operation. If you want to unbox **and** convert, then you need to double-cast. `(double)(int)i`. The `(int)i` is an unboxing cast, and the `(double)` is now an arithmetic conversion cast.

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList`?

Comment: You shouldn't be using ArrayList in the first place. Switch to better teaching materials.

Comment: Well, the point remains valid: you wouldn't be expected to use `ArrayList` in production code anymore -- it was useful in .NET 1 when there were no generics, but that was a long time ago. So if you have teaching material that still teaches `ArrayList`, it's woefully out of date and should be replaced; if you've stumbled on it yourself out of curiosity, just skip it and go straight to learning about generics (even if you're storing mixed types, a `List<object>` is better, and illustrates the same issue).

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert
 Thank you.. i didnt knew ArrayList is outdated and I thought Lists can store only specific data types.. But I have a question.. Then List is non generic right? Please correct me if im wrong..

Comment: @Vikash - No, `List` is `List<T>`. It is generic. But `List<object>` is able to hold anything. Your code should use `List<double>`.