# Is List in C# generic or non Generic?

Tags: c#

According to my understanding, a generic is something which can only store a specific datatype in it.

In [my previous StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70313313/3025856), I asked a question using an `ArrayList` (a non-generic data type). In response, contributors told me not to use it as it outdated, and to instead use `List` which can also store different data types. Until now, I thought `List` could only only use a specific data type, but now I've come to understand that `List` can also store different data types in it:

```
List<object>
```

So, are lists generic or non-generic?

If my question feels dumb, please explain the actual difference between a generic and non-generic class.

Comment: It's generic because it's declared as `List<T>` where `T` can be any type (*including* `object`).

Comment: "List can store only a specific data type" means more exactly in case of reference types: "... or objects of derived types"

Comment: A generic type is just a type that has any number of type parameters, which includes `List<T>`. What types a collection can store is separate from the question of whether a type is generic or not: as mentioned, `List<object>` can hold any `object` (so everything) while I can write an `IntList` that is not generic and still only accepts `int`s. The "generic" part comes from not having to write `DoubleList`, `CharList` and so on, but just being able to use `List<T>` for all of them. `ArrayList`, in this scheme, might as well be called `ObjectList`.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [@Jeroen Mostert's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70314509/is-list-in-c-sharp-generic-or-non-generic#comment124296223_70314509):

> A generic type is just a type that has any number of type parameters, which includes `List<T>`. What types a collection can store is separate from the question of whether a type is generic or not: as mentioned, `List<object>` can hold any `object` (so everything) while I can write an `IntList` that is not generic and still only accepts `int`s. The "generic" part comes from not having to write `DoubleList`, `CharList` and so on, but just being able to use `List<T>` for all of them. `ArrayList`, in this scheme, might as well be called `ObjectList`.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, a generic class or method is one that defers the specification of one or more types until declaration. This allows the programmer to use a method or class with whatever type they want—and reduces the amount of code needed since the same class/method can be used with many types.

`List<T>` is a generic class that can be used with the type it is declared with; e.g., `List<int>` can store `int`s and `list<string>` can store `string`s.

`ArrayList` is like a list of `object`s (`List<object>`), but it is not generic because you cannot say you want to store `int`s or `string`s, for example.

Please refer to [the Microsoft documentation on generics in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics) for further reading.